# how to fix Lookup function error #N/A on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet, lookup

I have an issue error **#N/A** Message with VLOOKUP and LOOKUP function, as it is shown on the image I can't find out where is the error, can you help me guys

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you look up must be found in the first column of the vlookup range.
You can try reordering the columns in an virtual array. For the highlighted cell (in the image you shared) that would make the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP("5f8961ec", {$K$2:$K$26, $J$2:$J$26}, 2, false)
```

Of course, you can also replace the value '5f8961ec' with a cell reference.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

use in E1 after you delete everything in it:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {K2:K, J2:J}, 2, )))
```